# How to ask interactively for admin password when using Azure json deployment template from Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

**Context**

I've downloaded the automation script of my running Azure Windows VM.
I decided to use the Powershell script to automate the deployment.

The VM part of the json schema requires the "adminPassword". It was missing, so I added it, and introduced a parameter both in the template, and both in the parameter file:

**template.json**

```
"parameters": {
    "adminPassword": { "type": "securestring" },
...
...
"resources": [
     ...
     ...
     "osProfile": {
         "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_name')]",
         "adminUsername": "myname",
     "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
     "windowsConfiguration": {
         "provisionVMAgent": true,
         "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
     },
     "secrets": [],
     "allowExtensionOperations": true
},
```

**parameters.json**

```
"parameters": {
    "adminPassword": { "type": "securestring" }
```

Nice try, but somehow in deep I knew it will do nothing, I mean will ask interactively nothing. One or more step is missing... but I stuck here...

In "official" MS doc the author simply put the clear password into the parameters.json, what is a quite disturbing. see: [placing the clear password into the paramters.json?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template)

Comment: I actually found something...  https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2015/11/30/no-more-plaintext-passwords-using-azure-key-vault-with-azure-resource-manager/

Comment: why not, if you just run powershell or cli it will prompt you for all the missing parameter values

Comment: also, how do you think a person will supply kv ID interactively? :)

Comment: The fact it did not asked interactively, having the code above. Please note, the parameters are in the Azure template and not powershell parameters.

Comment: that doesnt matter. if you dont supply a value for a parameter you will get a prompt or an error, depending on how you invoke the template

Comment: yes, I got error if I do not provide the parameter. You wrote "...depending on how you invoke...". So how should I invoke the template?

Comment: azure powershell\az cli\portal will prompt for missing parameters. rest api\sdks will throw

Comment: I am running from my desktop. But now I got it: New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile and must not use the -TemplateParameterFile option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it and it work just like that, can you update your azure powershell, its probably badly outdated.

param:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "test": {
            "value": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "test": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "testo": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": []
}
```

powershell:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName NetworkWatcherRG -TemplateUri 'https://paste.ee/d/S2wJm/0' -TemplateParameterUri 'https://paste.ee/d/8rW6k/0'
```

it will prompt you for the missing parameter. same will happen if you use `TemplateParameterFile`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove a parameter from *.parameters.json file in order to get prompt. e.g

---

### template.json file

---

```
{
   "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01- 
             01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
   "parameters":{
      "alertName":{
         "minLength":1,
         "type":"String",
         "metadata":{
            "description":"CPU Percentage alert verifies the cpu usage of virtual machine 
                           and intimates to action group if threshold goes beyond that"
         }
      },
      "alertDescription":{
         "defaultValue":"Virtual Machines alert for CPU Percentage",
         "type":"String",
         "metadata":{
            "description":"Virtual Machines alert for CPU Percentage"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

---

### parameters.json

```
{
   "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01- 
   01/deploymentParameters.json#",
   "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
   "parameters":{
      "alertName":{
         "value":"CPU% Measurement"
      }
   }
}
```

---

---

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -name "CustomDeployment" -ResourceGroupName test -TemplateFile "C:\Users\sachin.kalia\template.json" -TemplateParameterFile "
C:\Users\sachin.kalia\parameters.json"
```

---

Once you execute an above command it will ask you for prompt to provide alertDescription.
I hope it will help you.